# How to upload a Python dictionary to DolphinDB with the original order?

Tags: python, dictionary, dolphindb

I want to upload a dictionary from my Python client to the DolphinDB server using the `session.upload(dict)` method. I would like to keep the original order of the dictionary after uploading. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the keys and values separately into lists, and upload the lists to the DolphinDB server. Then, create an ordered dictionary on the server. Refer to the following script:

```
d = {
"a": 1.1,
"b":1.2,
"a2": 1.3
}

s.upload({"k":list(d.keys())})
s.upload({"v":list(d.values())})
s.run("""
orderedDict1 = dict(k, v, true)
for(k in orderedDict1.keys()){
  print(k + ":" + orderedDict1[k])
}
""")
```